# Custom Select shows the default select too

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a custom select dropdown [from here](https://codepen.io/THEORLAN2/pen/Kaewmw).

It works somewhat. When I click on the arrow to the left, it works as expected but when I click anywhere in the select other than the arrow, I get the default select dropdown as shown below.

[image: That's when I don't click on the arrow]

This is my what I'm doing :

```
<div id="custom_selectBox" class="select_mate" data-mate-select="active" >
    <select name="" onchange="" onclick="return false;" id="">
        <option value="">Seleciona una Opcion </option>
        <option value="1">Select option 1</option>
        <option value="2" >Select option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Select option 3</option>
    </select>

    <p class="selecionado_opcion"  onclick="open_select(this)" ></p>

    <span onclick="open_select(this)" class="icon_select_mate" >
        <svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <path d="M7.41 7.84L12 12.42l4.59-4.58L18 9.25l-6 6-6-6z"/>
           <path d="M0-.75h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
        </svg>
    </span>
    <div class="cont_list_select_mate">
        <ul class="cont_select_int">  </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried it separately on a new html file. I put the CSS and JS in the same HTML file. And this is how it looks :

[image]

I've included both the css and js files correctly. I've not added any js code myself. Also, the default select doesn't actually select any option.

Comment: which browser ? it seems to work fine

Comment: Chrome. I tried in IE, doesn't work there too

Comment: <select name="" onchange="" onclick="return false;" id="">
What is the role of onclick="return false;" here ?

Comment: @Osama I'm not sure really, I'm not good with frontend. I got it from CodePen, I've included the link above. But I tried removing it, didn't make a difference

Comment: Delete it  I think it prevent the selection

Comment: Tried. No difference

Answer (score 0):

I added inline CSS to the select element with `display:none;` and it works perfectly now.